# What is the proper method to wire my new sub panel with three wires

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, subpanel

- I currently have a 100 amp service.
- Off of the meter I have a main 100 amp breaker on the exterior of my home.
- from the main breaker outside it feeds a small main lug load center “sub panel” on the inside of my home. With Less than 10 feet of conduit/wire connecting them.
- this sub panel is the load center for my entire home. I do not have any additional panels.
- I’m looking to simply change the main lug sub panel to a main breaker sub panel (100 amp 30/60 square d homeline plug on neutral)
- I want to keep the 100 amp main breaker outside.
- I want to be able to shut down the home from outside at the main when working on panel but also from inside at the sub.
- feeding the current sub panel inside is three wires. Two lines and a neutral. (NO GROUND WIRE FROM MAIN)
  Off of the conduit there is 10” of a braided bare copper ground wire going into the neutral/ground bus of the sub panel.
- with the stage set of what I have. I’m looking to better understand how I’m to wire up my new panel either the three wire and conduit

Comment: How do the wires get from the main breaker to the "main" subpanel?  Is it via conduit? Is the conduit metal and non-flexible?

Comment: Picture of the existing panel? Are neutrals and grounds mixed in the existing panel or on separate neutral and ground bars?

Comment: Can you post photos of where the feeder enters the existing subpanel please?

Comment: Curiosity: what's the goal? Why do you want an additional breaker indoors? You will be turning off the entire service rarely enough that going outside is no great hardship, and indeed turning it off from outside is better because it means *everything* in the panel box is de-energised so there's less risk. In my area at least this is now the standard configuration, replacing the old indoor main-breaker approach.

Comment: Harper. My bad. I meant to state above that the  raceway is metal conduit and non flexible.

Comment: I’m currently not where the panel is and do not have pictures but the current SP is flipped with the main neutral going into the the neutral bar and the lines wrapping around to bottom. The grounds and neutral are all mixed and matched together. There is a bonding bushing off the raceway nipple with bare copper wire going into neutral/ground bar

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me: the sub panel has neutral/ground bonding, then. That doesn't require a whole new panel to solve, simply flip the main breaker outside, separate all the neutrals/grounds inside, remove the neutral bond screw, and reenergize. I have a feeling that this question will be closed without some additional clarification - if that should happen, _please_ come back to [edit] in some pics and clarify your goals and the question will get reopened.

Comment: Actually, it sounds like _two_ questions in one: 1) separation of neutral/ground at the sub panel, and 2) why isn't the sub grounded back to the main.

Comment: Does the conduit ground the sub back to the main in this case? I’m ultimately looking for more spaces. I guess I also don’t understand how it passed inspection in 2021 if they are neutral and grounds are not separated.

Comment: Sounds to me like this isn't a "sub panel" it's the main panel, and has been called a "sub panel" in this question to differentiate it from the "main breaker" outside. If this is correct, your "sub panel" should have neutral and ground tied together. Terminology is difficult for laypersons, which is why **photos** were requested. We can see things you wouldn't think to mention.